# taken data from firebase change color in javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase

```
<table class="table is-striped is-narrow is-hoverable is-fullwidth">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>symbol</th>
            <th>doji dragon</th>
            <th>doji grave</th>
            <th>timeframe</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="myTable">
        </tbody>
var ref12 = collection(db,"doji4h");
const querySnapshot1 = await getDocs(ref12);
querySnapshot1.forEach((doc2) => {




 let data2 = doc2.data();
            let row  = `<tr>
                            <td>${data2.symbol}</td>
                            <td bgcolor=greencolor>${data2.doji_dragon}</td>
                            <td bgcolor=redcolor>${data2.doji_grave}</td>
                             <td>${data2.timeframe}</td>
                      </tr>`;
            let table = document.getElementById('myTable2')
           table.innerHTML += row
   });
let dojidragoncolor= data2.doji_dragon;
let dojigravecolor= data2.doji_grave;
if (dojidragoncolor === Bullish){
greencolor="green";}
else{
greencolor="white";

}

if (dojigravecolor === Bearish){
redcolor="red";}
else{
redcolor="white";
}
```

I want to change color of data2doji_dragon and data2.doji_grave. red and green according to bullish or bearish string come from firebase

all the data is green now . there is a notation problem I have it seems

Answer (score 0):

Try changing two things.

#### 1. Calculate the values of `redcolor` and `greencolor` earlier

At the moment you are creating them *after* the time you want to read them.
Move the "if (doji ..." statements before the "let row ..."

#### 2. Mark the term 'greencolor' as needing interpolation

Currently you are using

```
bgcolor = greencolor
```

If I remember correctly, the browser will read that as a string:

```
bgcolor = "greencolor"
```

And it handles that unknown color "greencolor" by ignoring the last part, so that it is behaving as though you had written:

```
bgcolor = "green"
```

#### Here is what I propose:

(As the first attempt was unsuccessful, I have added extra information into the displayed table cell, for diagnostic purposes.)

```
let data2 = doc2.data();

let dojidragoncolor = data2.doji_dragon;
let dojigravecolor = data2.doji_grave;
if (dojidragoncolor === Bullish) {
  greencolor = "green";
} else {
  greencolor = "white";

}

if (dojigravecolor === Bearish) {
  redcolor = "red";
} else {
  redcolor = "white";
}

let row = `
<tr>
 <td bgcolor="${greencolor}">${data2.doji_dragon} ${greencolor}</td>
 <td bgcolor="${redcolor}">${data2.doji_grave} ${redcolor}</td>
</tr>`;
```

Comment: sorry ıt ıs not working

Comment: Try now - I have added double-quotes around the interpolation of the bgcolor values inside the td's, and I have added display of the colors themselves so you can check where the problem is. Let me know what it displays.

Comment: hello I solve the problem. The problem where the code stay.

Answer (score 0):

```
let data2 = doc2.data();// it have to be after this line 
const dojidragoncolor= data2.engulfing_bullish;
const dojigravecolor= data2.engulfing_bearish;

let bullcolor =""
let bearcolor = ""

if (dojidragoncolor == "Bullish"){
bullcolor="green";}
else{
bullcolor="white";

}

if (dojigravecolor == "Bearish"){
bearcolor="red";}
else{
bearcolor="white";
}
console.log(bullcolor);
console.log(bearcolor);
 let row  = `<tr>
                            <td>${data2.symbol}</td>
                            <td bgcolor=${bullcolor}>${data2.engulfing_bullish}</td>
                           <td bgcolor=${bearcolor}>${data2.engulfing_bearish}</td>
                             <td>${data2.timeframe}</td>
                      </tr>`;
            let table = document.getElementById('myTable2')
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.